# Why is my method not running all the way through?

Tags: java, linked-list, runtime-error

I'm working on a Sorted Double-Linked List assignment that sorts dates, and this is a method I have to write to test my code. When running however my code stops at

```
"When searching for the date: 12/10/2023 contains() returns true"
```

even though its only a system.out.println statement and should be able to continue on. The "contains" method that I am calling only returns a boolean. Any ideas as to why my code is stopping?

```
//in main class
public static void test(SortedLList2<Date> list) {

    System.out.println("The list displayed:");
    list.display();
    System.out.println("The list displayed backwards:");
    list.displayBackwards();
    int year = list.getEntry(list.getLength() - 1).getYear();
    int month = list.getEntry(list.getLength() - 1).getMonth();
    int day = list.getEntry(list.getLength() - 1).getDay();
    Date newEntry = new Date(month, day, year);
    System.out.println("When searching for the date: " + newEntry.toString() + " contains() returns " + list.contains(newEntry));
    System.out.println("When removing the date: " + newEntry.toString() + " remove() returns" + list.remove(newEntry));
    Date defaultDate = new Date(1, 1, 1000);
    System.out.println("When searching for the date: " + defaultDate.toString() + " contains() returns "
            + list.contains(defaultDate));
    System.out.println("When trying to remove the date: " + defaultDate.toString() + " remove() returns "
            + list.remove(defaultDate));
    System.out.println("The list displayed:");
    list.display();
    System.out.println("The list displayed backwards:");
    list.displayBackwards();

    testSortedLList2(list);
}

//in the SortedLList2 class
public boolean contains(T anEntry) {
    Node2 currNode = firstDummyNode.getNextNode();

    while (currNode != lastDummyNode ) {
        if (anEntry.compareTo(currNode.getData()) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            currNode = currNode.getNextNode();
    } // end while
    return false;
}
```

Comment: maybe you are not running this version of the code? Or it is throwing an uncaught exception? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Where's the code for `remove()`?

Comment: It looks like your have an infinite loop in your `remove` function, which you haven't included the source for.